# NSLocale Language Issue

Tags: ios, locale, nslocale

So in my app I am trying to get the devices currently set language and its acronym. So I do this:

```
NSString *fullLanguage = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]];
NSString *abrlanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

However some users report that the language is returning something like: en_UK or something similar, which in turn is messing up the functionality of my app.

Anyway is there a way to get the currently set language of the device regardless if the devices regional settings?

Thanks!

Comment: I am expecting it to just say "en" without any additional regional information behind it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get the language code, use:

```
NSString *languageCode = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
NSLog(@"%@", languageCode);  // Prints "en"
```

To get the full name of the language:

```
NSString *languageName = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:languageCode];
NSLog(@"%@", languageName);  // Prints "English"
```

Note that you were using the region code (which provides for regional variations of languages), and could be gotten easier like this:

```
NSString *regionCode = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier];
NSLog(@"%@", regionCode);  // Prints "en_US"
```

Region codes start with the language code, followed by the underscore, and then the regional variation.  (This is standardized per Apple's documentation.)

Also, if you use `currentLocale`, know that it is not updated as the users preferences are changed.  Use `autoupdatingCurrentLocale` instead if you want to keep it in sync if they change.